# Drawing tools eyedropper crashes Mathematica 12.1 with MengerMesh

Tags: mesh, crash, drawing

Mathematica 12.1.1 under macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

1. In a new notebook, evaluate: `MengerMesh[0, 3]`
2. Click once on the output's graphic image, which causes the bounding box to appear.
3. From menu Graphics select Drawing Tools.
4. Select the eyedropper on the palette that opens.
5. Click on the graphic image.
6. Mathematica quits unexpectedly!

(Credit for discovering the bug (on macOS) goes to Mark Normand.)

Comment: Please file a report with Wolfram Tech Support

Comment: Nice bug find. Also occurs on Windows 10.

Comment: The person who first discovered the bug has reported it. I'll do the same.